# how can hide to pull the drop down menu?

Tags: android

i am creating an module in which i want to restrict the user to pull down the drop down menu.Actually I do not want to allow the user to drop the menu down and acces the setting options. I have used this line of code.

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);`

and this is hide the drop down menu but my activity touch is not working now i am touching any where on screen it is not performing any task.So any one can please help me to solve this problem

Comment: simply return true in your ontouch(..) Method

Comment: i have done but still not working